# The Kimberling Sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, number-theory

#### Introduction

Of course, we've got a lot of [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges, so here is another one.

The Kimberling sequence ([A007063](http://oeis.org/A007063)) goes as following:

```
1, 3, 5, 4, 10, 7, 15, 8, 20, 9, 18, 24, 31, 14, 28, 22, ...
```

This is produced by shuffling the normal iteration:

```
[1] 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

The first term of the sequence is `1`. After that, we reshuffle the sequence until all the terms on the left are used. The shuffling has the pattern `right - left - right - left - ...`. Since there are no terms at the left of the `1`, there is no shuffling. We get the following:

```
 2 [3] 4  5  6  7  8  9
```

On the i<sup>th</sup> iteration, we discard the i<sup>th</sup> item and put that in our sequence. This is the **2nd** iteration, so we discard the **2nd** item. The sequence becomes: `1, 3`. For our next iteration, we are going to shuffle the current iteration with the pattern above. We take the first unused item at the right of the i<sup>th</sup> item. This happens to be `4`. We will append this to our new iteration:

```
 4
```

Now we're going to take the first unused item at the left of the i<sup>th</sup> item. This is `2`. We will append this to our new iteration:

```
 4  2
```

Since there are no items left at the left of the i<sup>th</sup> item, we'll just append the rest of the sequence to the new iteration:

```
 4  2 [5] 6  7  8  9  10  11  ...
```

This is our **3rd** iteration, so we'll discard the **3rd** item, which is `5`. This is the third item in our sequence:

```
 1, 3, 5
```

To get the next iteration, just repeat the process. I've made a gif if it isn't clear:

[image]

<sup>The gif took me longer than writing the actual post</sup>

#### Task

- Given an non-negative integer **n**, output the first **n** terms of the sequence
- You may provide a function or a program
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

#### Test cases:

```
Input: 4
Output: 1, 3, 5, 4

Input: 8
Output: 1, 3, 5, 4, 10, 7, 15, 8

Input: 15
Output: 1, 3, 5, 4, 10, 7, 15, 8, 20, 9, 18, 24, 31, 14, 28
```

**Note:** The commas in the output are not necessary. You may for example use newlines, or output a list, etc.

Comment: I'm working on a method using stack rotation

Comment: @Cyoce Good luck :)

Comment: it's looking like I'll need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, 22 bytes

```
JS*3QVQ@JN=J.i>JhN_<JN
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JS%2A3QVQ%40JN%3DJ.i%3EJhN_%3CJN&input=10)

Simply performs the shuffling technique described in the OP.

#### Explanation:

```
JS*3QVQ@JN=J.i>JhN_<JN
JS*3Q                    assign the list [1, 2, ..., 3*input-1] to J
     VQ                  for N in range(Q):
       @JN                  print J[N]
            .i              interleave 
              >JhN             J[N+1:] with
                  _<JN         reverse J[:N]
          =J                assign the resulting list to J
```

Answer (score 6):

## Julia, <s>78</s> 71 bytes

```julia
n->[(i=j=x;while j<2i-3 j=i-(j%2>0?1-j:j+2)÷2;i-=1end;i+j-1)for x=1:n]
```

This is an unnamed function that accepts an integer and returns an integer array. To call it, assign it to a variable.

The approach here is the same as that described on OEIS.

Ungolfed:

```julia
# This computes the element of the sequence
function K(x)
    i = j = x
    while j < 2i - 3
        j = i - (j % 2 > 0 ? 1 - j : j + 2)÷2
        i -= 1
    end
    return i + j - 1
end

# This gives the first n terms of the sequence
n -> [K(i) for i = 1:n]
```

Saved 7 bytes thanks to Mauris!

Answer (score 3):

## APL, <s>56</s> 44 bytes

```
{⍵<⍺+⍺-3:(⍺-1)∇⍺-4÷⍨3+(1+2×⍵)×¯1*⍵⋄⍺+⍵-1}⍨¨⍳
```

This is an unnamed monadic train that accepts an integer on the right and returns an array. It's roughly the same approach as [my Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67569/20469).

The innermost function is a recursive dyadic function that returns the *n*th term in the Kimberling sequence, given *n* as identical left and right arguments.

```
{⍵<⍺+⍺-3:                                    ⍝ If ⍵ < 2⍺ - 3
         (⍺-1)∇⍺-4÷⍨3+(1+2×⍵)×¯1*⍵           ⍝ Recurse, incrementing a and setting
                                             ⍝ ⍵ = ⍺ - (3 + (-1)^⍵ * (1 + 2⍵))/4
                                   ⋄⍺+⍵-1}   ⍝ Otherwise return ⍺ + ⍵ - 1
```

With that in hand, we're able to get individual terms of the sequence. However, the problem then becomes that this is a *dyadic* function, meaning it requires arguments on both sides. Enter the `⍨` operator! Given a function `f` and an input `x`, `f⍨x` is the same as `x f x`. So in our case, referring to the aforementioned function as `f`, we can construct the following monadic train:

```
f⍨¨⍳
```

We apply `f` to each integer from 1 to the input, yielding an array.

Saved 12 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 130 bytes

```
(n=0;s={};Nest[(n++;AppendTo[s,z=#[[n]]];Flatten[TakeDrop[#,1+2(n-1)]/.{t___,z,r___}:> 
Riffle[{r},Reverse@{t}]])&,Range[3*#],#];s)&
```

We begin with a list consisting of the range from `1` to `3x`, where `x` is the desired number of Kimberling sequence terms.

At each step, `n`, `TakeDrop` breaks the  the current list into a front list of `2n+1` terms (where the work is done) and rear list (which will be later joined with the reworked front list).   The front list is matched with the following pattern, `{t___,z,r___}` where z is the Kimberling term at the center of the front list.  `r` is `Riffle`'d with the reverse of `t` and then the rear list is appended. `z` is removed and appended to (`AppendTo`) the growing Kimberling sequence.

`n` is incremented by `1` and the current list is processed by the same function via `Nest.`

---

**Example**

```
(n=0;s={};Nest[(n++;AppendTo[s,z=#[[n]]];Flatten[TakeDrop[#,1+2(n-1)]/.{t___,z,r___}:> 
Riffle[{r},Reverse@{t}]])&,Range[3*#],#];s)&[100]
```

> {1, 3, 5, 4, 10, 7, 15, 8, 20, 9, 18, 24, 31, 14, 28, 22, 42, 35, 33,
> 46, 53, 6, 36, 23, 2, 55, 62, 59, 76, 65, 54, 11, 34, 48, 70, 79, 99,
> 95, 44, 97, 58, 84, 25, 13, 122, 83, 26, 115, 82, 91, 52, 138, 67,
> 90, 71, 119, 64, 37, 81, 39, 169, 88, 108, 141, 38, 16, 146, 41, 21,
> 175, 158, 165, 86, 191, 45, 198, 216, 166, 124, 128, 204, 160, 12,
> 232, 126, 208, 114, 161, 156, 151, 249, 236, 263, 243, 101, 121, 72,
> 120, 47, 229}

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 76 bytes

```
for a in range(input()):
 b=a+1
 while-~b<2*a:b=a-(b^b%-2)/2;a-=1
 print a+b
```

### Explanation

This is the OEIS formula after many golf-y transformations! It worked out *beautifully*. The original code was

```
i=b=a+1
while b<2*i-3:b=i-(b+2,1-b)[b%2]/2;i-=1
print i+b-1
```

I first got rid of `i`, replacing it with `a+1` everywhere and expanding the expressions:

```
b=a+1
while b<2*a-1:b=a+1-(b+2,1-b)[b%2]/2;a-=1
print a+b
```

Then, rewrote `b<2*a-1` as `-~b<2*a` to save a byte of whitespace, and moved the `+1` into the selection, division by 2, and negation:

```
while-~b<2*a:b=a-(b,-b-1)[b%2]/2;a-=1
```

Then, `-b-1` is just `~b`, so we can write `(b,~b)[b%2]`. This is equivalent to `b^0 if b%2 else b^-1` using the XOR operator, or alternatively, `b^b%-2`.

```
while-~b<2*a:b=a-(b^b%-2)/2;a-=1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>29</s> 25 bytes

```
VQ+.W<hHyN-~tN/x%Z_2Z2hNN
```

Jakube saved 4 bytes, but I have no clue how to read the code anymore.

Here is the old solution:

```
VQKhNW<hKyN=K-~tN/x%K_2K2)+KN
```

Translation of my Python answer. I'm not very good at Pyth, so maybe there's still ways to shorten this.

```
VQ                              for N in range(input()):
  KhN                             K = N+1
     W<hKyN                       while 1+K < 2*N:
           =K-~tN/x%K_2K2)         K = (N--) - (K%-2 xor K) / 2
                          +KN     print K + N
```

Comment: You can use `.W` to golf off 4 bytes: `VQ+.W<hHyN-~tN/x%Z_2Z2hNN`.

Comment: That's cool -- could you roughly explain how it works?

Comment: `.W` has the form: `.W<condition><apply><start-value>`. I used the start value `hN`, like you did in `KhN`. `.W` changes  this value as long as the `<condition>` is true. I used the same condition as you `<hHyN`. The condition is a lambda-function with the parameter `H`, so the current value (in your code `K`) is `H`. And I also used the same `<apply>` statement as you, I only replaced `K` with `Z`, because the `<apply>` statement is a lambda-function with parameter `Z`. We can ignore the `=K`, `.W` handles this. It replaces the old value with the calculated one. At the end print `+...N`